# Have an issue when calling a callback function from finally block

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have an issue when calling a callback function from finally block under an asyn function. This issue only happens when deploy the web release version to web server.

To deploy web, I do followings.

1. Build web project using: flutter build web
2. Deploy web release folder to a real server
3. Connect to web using Chrome: https://192.168.96.102:1443/#/

My codes are as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
    "Id": 78912,
    "Customer": "Jason Sweet",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Price": 18.00
  };
  print("Doing JSON POST ...");
  await request(
      "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json",
      payload,
      (error, Map<String, dynamic> resp) {
        print(resp);
        print(resp["success"]);   
        print("xxx");
      });
  print("JSON POST Done!");
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // Codes are ommited for simple 
}

Future<void> request(uri, payload, callback) async {
  var _resp;
  int errorCode = -1;

  Map<String, String> _headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  };
  try {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(uri),
        body: json.encode(payload),
        headers: _headers).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));

    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 204) {
      errorCode = 0;
    }

    if (response.body != "") {
      try {
        _resp = (json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
      } catch (_) {
        try {
          _resp = (json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>);
        } catch (_) {
          errorCode = -1;
          _resp = {}.cast<String, dynamic>();
        }
      }
    }
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    errorCode = -1;
  } finally {
    callback(errorCode, _resp); // *** Doubt that invoke "callback" funtion in "finally" block caused issue. 
  }
}
```

When calling below codes:

```
  print("Doing JSON POST ...");
  await request(
      "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json",
      payload,
      (error, Map<String, dynamic> resp) {
        print(resp);
        print(resp["success"]);    // Crashed at this line 
        print("xxx");
      });
  print("JSON POST Done!");
```

I expect that followings shall be printed:

```
Doing JSON POST ...
{success: true}
true
xxx
POST Done!
```

But In fact, the output like this:

```
main.dart.js:15357 Doing JSON POST ...
main.dart.js:1741 Fetch finished loading: GET "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Me5WZLCzYlKw.ttf".
main.dart.js:15357 {success: true}
main.dart.js:3671 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'j')
at a_l.$2 (main.dart.js:46822)
at main.dart.js:14958
at ZL.a (main.dart.js:4846)
at ZL.$2 (main.dart.js:26907)
at YQ.$1 (main.dart.js:26901)
at XI.TZ (main.dart.js:27546)
at XI.uA (main.dart.js:27548)
at Wm.$0 (main.dart.js:27163)
at Object.nz (main.dart.js:4957)
at U.hy (main.dart.js:27087)
```

Flutter Info:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Could any one help me explain why this issue come? Thank you.

Comment: `_resp` is not necessarily initialized when the `finally` block is executed.  Also, you should declare it as `Map<String, dynamic>?`  instead of with `var`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks. Using "Map<String, dynamic>? _resp;" does not help.

Comment: The second suggestion was so that the variable is correctly typed (and to avoid the need for at least some of the casts).  Did the first suggestion to initalize the variable help?

Comment: I don't understand.  As I stated, using `Map<String, dynamic>? _resp;` isn't supposed to fix your problem.  *Initializing* `_resp` (e.g. `var _resp = <String, dynamic>{};`) should help because that would prevent `callback` from being invoked with an uninitialized argument.

Comment: In my example code, the code line `_resp = (json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>)` was called normally, then the `_resp` was initialized before finally block. As you can see in my posted log, the `_resp` json was already printed: `{success: true}`. However, accessing to map member `resp["success"]` caused the error. That's the thing I fell very strange.

Comment: This only happen with web release build. Not happen with mobile build or with web debugger.

Comment: Since uninitialized variables should be implicitly initialized to `null` and since it occurs only in a release build, it sounds like a bug, maybe from an overly aggressive optimization.  You should consider making a small, reproducible case and filing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

@jamesdlin You're right. Initializing _resp by `Map<String, dynamic> _resp = {};` solved the issue. However I'm so unclear why I don't get issue if calling "callback" out side of finally block even not initializing _resp. Following codes works OK.

```
Future<void> request(uri, payload, callback) async {
  var _resp;
  int errorCode = -1;

  Map<String, String> _headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  };
  try {
    // Omitted some codes for simple 
    // ...

    callback(errorCode, _resp);  // This calling is OK even when no initializing for _resp 
  } catch (e) {
    errorCode = -1;
    callback(-1, null);
  } finally {
    // callback(errorCode, _resp);  // Failed if calling in the finally block when no initializing for _resp
  }
}
```